# AWS Unmount Volume without Deleting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

How should I unmount a drive well ensuring it wont be deleted?
We want to move

```
vol-0de12fb88020aa624
from i-0b727a35caea24013 to i-0dff0911c0ebf45f9
```

we want to move the volume, do not want copy files from one EBS volume to another EBS volume ?? I have EBS Snapshot enable already .
can anyone advice me with the best way for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the best way to do it but i would take a snapshot and creating a new EBS volume from it and attach it to the new instance and after see that all is good remove the old one. Doing it like this you don't remove a working state before getting a new up.

Read on restoring snapshots here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/backup-recovery/restore.html

Comment: Thnaks Erik Asplund, how fast does/can unmounting result in deleting of the volume?